# Which Haman is right?

Tags: quran, bible

In the Bible, Haman is said to be the helper of the Babylonian king who lived 1,100 years after Moses and persecuted the Jews.

In Quran, Haman is said to be the minister of the pharaoh and associated with him in his court at the time of Moses.

Bible came first so I think Quran is wrong. What is right?

Comment: Try adding references

Comment: Most names are used by multiple people! This is no exception.

Comment: Please add the reference where Quran mention that!

Answer (score 1):

The biblical book of Esther I believe mentions Haman as a builder of the tower of Babylon.

Muslim were made fun of this fact till the Egyptian language was rediscovered as it was dead even before Prophet Muhammad(Peace and Blessing Be Upon Him).

Maurice Bucaille a fellow historian and researcher converted to Islam due to these startling discoveries(and other reasons).

> The Rosetta stone played a key part in helping decipher the forgotten
>   language.

They were able to find Egyptian records showing Haman as an architect in the time of the Pharaoh King Ramses II(by approx). This blunder is well known and can be read about online, **this proves that the bible has been corrupted by man.**

> And Pharaoh said, "O Haman, construct for me a tower that I might
>   reach the ways - The ways into the heavens - so that I may look at the
>   deity of Moses; but indeed, I think he is a liar." And thus was made
>   attractive to Pharaoh the evil of his deed, and he was averted from
>   the [right] way. And the plan of Pharaoh was not except in
>   ruin.(Ghafir 36-37)

Many websites will avoid telling you about Maurice and his discoveries and the solid proof behind his research, his books "Moses and Pharaoh in the Bible, Qur'an and History", 
"Bible, the Qur'an and science may intrest you if your truly earnest in getting both sides.

[Quran Source](https://quran.com/40/36-37)

**I'll give you the specific sources in a week or less in the comments as I need to compile them.**

> **AND ALLAH KNOWS BEST, MAY ALLAH FORGIVE ME FOR ANY MISTAKES**

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no historical evidence of Moses even having lived; can you give a reference to historical evidence that he did? Otherwise, there also can't be historical evidence for him having met someone called Haman, or being the contemporary of such a person.

Comment: If the Quran mentioned Haman as a chief architect for the Pharaoh, and was later discovered to be correct in Egyptian records.                                                                                                       "The name “Haman” was indeed mentioned in Egyptian inscriptions. This name was referred to in a monument in the Hof Museum in Vienna". If Haman was mentioned in the Quran correctly while other scriptures failed in doing so, I think it's safe to assume that Moses also existed. [Source](http://quranalhakeem.com/haman-and-ancient-egypt-monuments/)

Comment: "If Haman was mentioned in the Quran correctly while other scriptures failed in doing so, I think it's safe to assume that Moses also existed." That doesn't follow at all. If some figure from the Arthur myth proves historical, that doesn't mean Merlin the wizard exists.

Comment: An an incompatible analogy, I wouldn't even dare to compare Moses(peace be upon him) to a mythical wizard. Some aspects of Islam rely solely on faith and do not require absolute proof. The body of the Pharaoh was found to have a higher degree of salt content then usual dead bodies and the body was surprisingly well preserved for that which led Maurice to convert, he even wrote a book on it. The higher the salt content suggest of being drowned, and the story of Moses(Peace be upon him) agrees. May god have mercy on Moses(Peace be upon him).